# Simplify CASE in VB.net code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Hey all, i am looking here to see if anyone would have a better way to acomplish this task below in less code.

```
Select Case mainMenu.theNumOpened
            Case 1
                Me.Text = "NBMsg1"
                Me.SetDesktopLocation(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, 5)
            Case 2
                Me.Text = "NBMsg2"
                Dim hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg1")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, Me.Height + 10, 0, 0, 1)
                Me.SetDesktopLocation(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, 5)
            Case 3
                Me.Text = "NBMsg3"
                Dim hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg2")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, Me.Height + 10, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg1")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, (Me.Height * 2) + 15, 0, 0, 1)
                Me.SetDesktopLocation(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, 5)
            Case 4
                Me.Text = "NBMsg4"
                Dim hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg3")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, Me.Height + 10, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg2")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, (Me.Height * 2) + 15, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg1")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, (Me.Height * 3) + 20, 0, 0, 1)
                Me.SetDesktopLocation(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, 5)
            Case 5
                Me.Text = "NBMsg5"
                Dim hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg4")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, Me.Height + 10, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg3")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, (Me.Height * 2) + 15, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg2")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, (Me.Height * 3) + 20, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg1")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, (Me.Height * 4) + 25, 0, 0, 1)
                Me.SetDesktopLocation(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, 5)
            Case 6
                Me.Text = "NBMsg6"
                Dim hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg5")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, Me.Height + 10, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg4")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, (Me.Height * 2) + 15, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg3")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, (Me.Height * 3) + 20, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg2")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, (Me.Height * 4) + 25, 0, 0, 1)
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg1")
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, (Me.Height * 5) + 30, 0, 0, 1)
                Me.SetDesktopLocation(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, 5)
            Case Else
                Me.Close()
                Me.Dispose()
        End Select
```

What it does is pass to it now many windows are currently already opened. So if one then of course it goes to case 1. If there are 2 opened then it moves the oldest down and puts the newest on top. etc etc. I have set it so that a max of 6 boxes can only be opened at one time.

If anyone knows how i could also "slide" them down (kinda like an effect of jQuery) then that would also be, well awesome to know! :o)

Any help/suggestions would be great! :o)

David

Comment: Anyone else have any more suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Since a lot of the code is either just repeated or just incrementing in some way, some kind of For loop is the way to go, I think the code below should work, but it might be off by 1 or similar:

```
If mainMenu.theNumOpened > 0 And mainMenu.theNumOpened <= 6 Then
    Me.Text = "NBMsg" & Cstr(mainMenu.theNumOpened)
    Dim hwnd As IntPtr
    Dim h as integer = 5
    For i As Integer = mainMenu.theNumOpened - 1 To 1 Step -1
        FindWindow(vbNullString, "NBMsg" & CStr(i))        
        h += Me.Height + 5
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, h, 0, 0, 1)
    Next
    Me.SetDesktopLocation(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 302, 5)
End If
```

Edit: Added fixes suggested by Mark

Comment: Suggested edits: Insert `Step -1` at `For` statement; and I believe `x` is actually `mainMenu.theNumOpened`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there was something I'd forgotten about the for loop but it's too long since I made a `backwards` loop in VB.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do that, ho. But it doesn't seem to move the next box down if there's more than 1 displaying? It just stacks them on top of each other.